# Error listing folder contents

Tags: go

Using Go 1.8.1, I'm trying to write something that handles files. The trouble is, while `filepath.Walk(...)` works ok, I need something a bit more flexible. So I turn to `ioutil.ReadDir(...)`, only to be greeted with a spectacular "`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`". I've tried alternatives (`filepath.Glob(...)`, `file.Readdirnames(...)`), they all result in the same error.
What's really puzzling is `filepath.Walk(...)` uses `os.Lstat(...)`, but when I try to use `os.Lstat(...)` directly... I get the same error above.
I've tried this on an updated Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and on an updated Fedora 25, it made no difference.

My Go-fu is really weak (this is my first application besides "hello world"), so any help is appreciated.

Here's some code that fails:

```
func glob() {
    infos, err := filepath.Glob("*")
    if err != nil {
        for _, info := range infos {
            fmt.Println(info)
        }
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}

func y() {
    file, err := os.Open(folder)
    println(file.Name())
    defer file.Close()
    infos, err := file.Readdirnames(0)
    //infos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(folder)
    if err != nil {
        for _, info := range infos {
            fmt.Println(info)
        }
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}

func readDir() {
    infos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(folder)
    if err != nil {
        for _, info := range infos {
            fmt.Println(info)
        }
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}
```

and here's what works:

```
func walk() {
    err := filepath.Walk(folder, printWalk)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(os.Stderr, "walk failed with error: %v\n", err)
    }
}

func printWalk(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("path:", path, "FileInfo.Name:", info.Name())
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Can you please update/edit your question with that code?

Comment: Stupid question: seeing how `folder` is a global variable, is it possible it didn't get initialised before the `readDir` func call?

Comment: Not really. It still fails if I replace with the string directly. And it is initialized, because y() prints its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `err` check looks backwards to me. I would have expected:

```
func readDir() {
    infos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(folder)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, info := range infos {
        fmt.Println(info)
    }
}
```

A more idiomatic version which has `folder` as a parameter and returns any error is:

```
func readDir(folder string) error {
    infos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(folder)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, info := range infos {
        fmt.Println(info)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Was just about to suggest to correct the `err` check

Comment: @peterSO thanks, my mistake was thinking that `infos` is unsafe to range in case of error. Was only trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the error wrongly.

```
if err != nil {  // if there is an error (!)
    // do something (as if there was no error)
} else {
    log.Fatal(err.Error()) // the dereference happens here, where err == nil.
}
```